# What is the difference between ProtoBuf.Serializer and ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel in protobuf-net?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

As I recently discovered we can serialize/deserialize in protobuf-net using two classes `ProtoBuf.Serializer` and `ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel`.
For example, let's say we have a custom class that we want to serialize/deserialize:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

We can do it in two ways:

1) Using `TypeModel`

```
TypeModel typeModel = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;
var person1 = new Person
{
    Name = "John",
    Age = 23
};

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    typeModel.Serialize(stream, person1);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var pesrson2 = typeModel.Deserialize(stream, null, typeof(Person));
}
```

2) Using `Serializer` (which is the chosen way in most of the tutorials I've seen)

```
var person1 = new Person
{
    Name = "John",
    Age = 23
};
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    Serializer.Serialize(stream, person1);
    stream.Position = 0;
    var pesrson2 = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(stream);
}
```

What is the difference between these two approaches. How to choose between these two? And what is `TypeModel` and `RuntimeTypeModel` in the first place?

Comment: One difference is if you pass `null` to `Serializer.Serialize` it will just write nothing, while `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.Serialize` will throw an exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the `Serializer.*` methods are *generally* just  convenience proxies to `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.*`. There are probably a few minor exceptions - those that don't touch a model at all (processing a "varint", for example)

Essentially, in the 1.* API, there was *only* one model. v2 added the ability to have concurrent/parallel models describing the same types, and a much richer runtime configuration system - all of this is encapsulated into `TypeModel` - with the *usual* implementation being `RuntimeTypeModel`. Note that you can *also* load assemblies that contain pre-baked `TypeModel` implementations, so not every `TypeModel` is a `RuntimeTypeModel`.

So; if you're using simple types with attributes : you're fine using `Serializer.*`. If you've had to do more advanced things with runtime configuration and multiple models - you'll need to keep track of your various `TypeModel` instances so you know which one to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please elaborate on what actually a `model` is, what it represents and more specifically `TypeModel`?

Comment: @MykhailoSeniutovych it is simply the set of types along with their configuration that the serializer knows about. When using `RuntimeTypeModel` it can figure that all out on-the-fly (caching the results per type as it needs), but for a pre-compiled model it can only ever serialize things that were known and specified when it was pre-compiled